# Reconciling schedule data (Solve a logic problem)

Tags: service, logic

I have a problem I need to solve using Node.  The question I have is surrounding the best logical way to solve it. Any advise is appreciated.

**Summary**

You  will  build  a  tool  that  imports  train  schedules  from  an  external  data  source  and  is  stored  in  an internal database.

**Eternal Data Source**

There is a service that provides a list of trains:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"A EXPRESS"},{"id":2,"name":"B EXPRESS"},{"id":3,"name":"C EXPRESS"},{"id":4,"name":"D EXPRESS"},{"id":5,"name":"E EXPRESS"}]
```

And a list of train stations:

Example for train "A EXPRESS":

```
[{"arrival":"2019-04-30T11:48:00.000Z","departure":"2019-05-01T05:42:00.000Z","service":"Loop 5","station":{"id":"ST1","name":"Waterloo"}},{"arrival":"2019-05-13T18:00:00.000Z","departure":"2019-05-14T05:00:00.000Z","service":"Loop 5","station":{"id":"ST2","name":"Paddington"}},{"arrival":"2019-05-15T04:00:00.000Z","departure":"2019-05-15T11:00:00.000Z","service":"Loop 5","station":{"id":"ST3","name":"Heathrow"}},{"arrival":"2019-05-16T20:00:00.000Z","departure":"2019-05-17T10:00:00.000Z","service":"Loop 5","station":{"id":"ST4","name":"Wimbledon"}},{"arrival":"2019-05-18T15:00:00.000Z","departure":"2019-05-19T21:00:00.000Z","service":"Loop 5","station":{"id":"ST5","name":"Reading"}},{"arrival":"2019-05-21T04:00:00.000Z","departure":"2019-05-21T21:00:00.000Z","service":"Loop 5","station":{"id":"ST6","name":"Algate"}},{"arrival":"2019-05-31T03:00:00.000Z","departure":"2019-05-31T15:00:00.000Z","service":"Loop 5","station":{"id":"ST1","name":"Waterloo"}}]
```

Note: this train stops at station "ST1" ("Waterloo") twice.

**To do**

For  each  imported  station  call,  we  want  to  maintain  the  latest  information  as  well as  the  history  of  the  station  call:

-What station is the train  calling?

-What are the latest  arrival  and  departure  dates?

-When was the station call first  imported?

-When was the station call last  updated?

-How did the station call  change  as  time  went?  (evolution  of  arrival  and  departure dates  with  time) This  kind  of  information  is  useful  for  us  to  understand  how  often  trains  are  delayed, when  do schedule  changes  happen  and  if  there  are  patterns  to  these  changes.

**How it works**

-The external  data  source  is  a  simulation  of  train  schedules  forecasts

-The data  covers  a  time  range  from  January  1st  2019  to  May  31st  2019

-This 5 months time  window is  compressed  and  simulated  over  a  24  hours  cycle

-This 24 hours cycle  restarts  every  day  at  00:00  UTC

-The data source  provides  endpoints  to  request  train  schedules

-A train list  endpoint  provides  a  dynamic  list  of  trains  that  you  can import (see Data above)

-A train schedules  endpoint  provides  a  dynamic  list  of  stations  calls  for  a specific  train (see Data above)

-A train schedule  consists  of  a  list  of  station  calls  with  a  varying  amount  of  past  station calls  and  future  station  calls

-This external  data  source  does  not  provide  a  unique  identifier  for  each  station   call

-This means that  merging  station  calls  is  not  straightforward. **This  is  the  crux  of  my question**:  reconciling  external  station   calls  with  the  existing  ones  in  the database.

-Station calls  arrival  and  departure  dates  routinely  change,  sometimes  by  multiple days.  Sometimes  they  swap,  get  deleted  or  new  ones  appear

-Station calls  can  sometimes  be  deleted  (the  train  will  not  stop  in  that  specific  station

-New station calls  can  sometimes  be  created  (the  train  will  make  an  unscheduled stop)

-The train  schedules  endpoint  changes  the  data  returned  every  15  minutes.

**Specific  requirements**

You  need  to  capture  24  hours  of  all  train  schedules  starting  at  00:00:00  UTC  on  one day  and  ending  at  23:59:59  UTC  on  the  same  day.

**Question**

As you can see from the task above, there is a need to reconcile the new imported data with existing data as the new data changes.

There is no ID that can be used to match station visits, but these visits need to be updated when the external data changes.

We do have a train ID and a station ID as well as the date of visits.

What is the logic I can apply to keep the database data accurate and up to date?

Thank you

**Answer?**

My initial thoughts are to do the following, however I am not sure if this is the best solution. If you have a better solution, or see a problem with mine, please let me know.

The list of station calls retrieved from the external service will always be saved to the internal database under its retrieval timestamp. This will always be displayed as the current information in the UI (latest database entry).

Each 15 min a call is made to the external service and a new latest entry is added to the internal database, and reflected on the UI.

The status of the latest entry needs to reflect the difference between the the latest entry and the previous entry.  E.g. delayed by X min, cancelled, etc. This is the tricky part, because the current station visit needs to be matched with a previous station visit.

My thinking is for a specific train is to just find the matching station ID.

- If there is no previous matching station ID, then the status is "new".
- if there is previous station ID, and no matching current station ID, the status is "cancelled".
- if there is one matching station ID, then there times are compared, and the status is updated to "early" or "delayed".
- If there is more than one matching station ID, the station previous and current station IDs with the closest timestamps are matched, and their status updates accordingly to "early" or "delayed".

Is my logic correct?